# Guardar valor en variable ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Necesito guardar los ID que pasan a travez de la url

> http://localhost:50210/familiares/Create/1009

Necesito capturar ese valor "1009" y llevarlo a un

```
<input name="codigo" type="text"class="form-control" value="AQUI
 NECESITO QUE ESTE ESE VALOR DE LA URL"/>
```

Necesito guardar ese valor en una variable.

Mi vista

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>tb_familiares</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombres, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombres, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombres, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.documento_identidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.documento_identidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.documento_identidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sexo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sexo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parentesco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parentesco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parentesco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.celular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.celular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.celular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cod_colaborador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
```

//AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO ESE INPUT CON ESE ID//

```
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cod_colaborador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cod_colaborador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mi controlador

```
namespace WebApplicationSIOldMutual.Controllers
{
    public class familiaresController : Controller
    {
        private sioldmutualEntities db = new sioldmutualEntities();

        // GET: familiares
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.tb_familiares.ToList());
        }

        // GET: familiares/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            tb_familiares tb_familiares = db.tb_familiares.Find(id);
            if (tb_familiares == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tb_familiares);
        }

        // GET: familiares/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: familiares/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_familiar,nombres,documento_identidad,fecha_nacimiento,sexo,parentesco,celular,telefono,cod_colaborador")] tb_familiares tb_familiares)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tb_familiares.Add(tb_familiares);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(tb_familiares);
        }

        // GET: familiares/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            tb_familiares tb_familiares = db.tb_familiares.Find(id);
            if (tb_familiares == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tb_familiares);
        }

        // POST: familiares/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id_familiar,nombres,documento_identidad,fecha_nacimiento,sexo,parentesco,celular,telefono,cod_colaborador")] tb_familiares tb_familiares)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tb_familiares).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tb_familiares);
        }

        // GET: familiares/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            tb_familiares tb_familiares = db.tb_familiares.Find(id);
            if (tb_familiares == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tb_familiares);
        }

        // POST: familiares/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            tb_familiares tb_familiares = db.tb_familiares.Find(id);
            db.tb_familiares.Remove(tb_familiares);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Mi archivo de rutas

```
namespace WebApplicationSIOldMutual
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Soy bastante nuevo en asp.net mvc5.

Comment: una pregunta,¿Tienes un controlador llamado `HomeControler`?

Comment: si señor si lo tengo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero que nada te aconsejo que estudies más el concepto del MVC.

La manera *MVC* de hacer lo que indicas es como sigue:

1. Crea un modelo que contenga la información que vas a necesitar en la vista:

   ```
   public class MiModelo
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       ...
       /* Puedes establecer un constructor para el modelo que tome los
          parámetros que quieras: */

       public MiModelo(int id)
       {
            this.ID = id;
       }
   }
   ```
2. En el controlador crea una acción (`ActionResult`) que espere ese parámetro que le vas a mandar y manda el modelo a la vista:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(int id)
   {
       return View(new Models.MiModelo(id));
   }
   ```
3. En la vista consumes el Modelo que pasaste a través del controlador; el primer paso es declararlo:

   ```
   // Asumiendo que lo haces con el motor Razor
   @model MiProyecto.Models.MiModelo
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "- Index";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
   ...
   ```

   y colocas la propiedad del modelo donde quieras dentro de la vista:

   ```
   <input name="codigo" type="text"class="form-control" value="@Model.ID"/>
   ```

Como te dije al principio, necesitas documentarte más sobre el concepto de MVC, te dejo un pequeño [tutorial](https://www.genbetadev.com/formacion/tutorial-de-iniciacion-en-asp-net-mvc-con-visual-studio-2013) y por aquí [otro](http://devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/525/Patron-MVC-Modelo-Vista-Controlador.aspx) para que empieces.
¡Saludos!

---

**EDIT**

Partiendo de la aclaración que haces, lo único que necesitas es recibir ese parámetro `id` en la acción `Create`, en lo demás es igual, salvo que puedes tener un constructor vacío para el modelo:

```
public class tb_familiares
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
    public tb_familiares() { }
}
```

y en tu controlador asignarle el valor de ese ID:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    return View(new tb_familiares() { ID = id });
}
```

y en la vista:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control disabled" } }) <!-- Nota el "disabled" -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Sin usar un modelo

En tu `RouteConfig.cs` ahí defines las `url` amigables, es decir:

quieres acceder a `http://localhost:50210/familiares/Index/1009` debes tener una ruta configurada de esta forma:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Familiares",
    url: "Familiares/Index/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Familiares", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

> `id = UrlParameter.Optional` indica que no siempre sera necesario el `id`,
>   si lo que quieres es que sea necesario solo quita lo antes mencionado.
>
> En el `RouteConfig.cs` hay una ruta por defecto que de igual manera te serviría y no seria necesario agregar esta que te menciono

en tu controlador debes tener algo así:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id){
    ViewBag.id = id;//guardando el valor de 1009
    return View()
}
```

En tu vista.

```
<input name="codigo" type="text"class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.id"/>
```

---

## Usando un modelo

teniendo el siguiente modelo:

```
public class ModeloUrl{
    public int id {get; set;}
}
```

en el controlador quedaría de esta forma:

```
@using Proyect1.Models;

public ActionResult Index(int id){
    ModeloUrl model = new ModeloUrl();
    model.id = id;
    return View(model)
}
```

en la vista tendrías algo así:

```
@model Proyect1.Models.ModeloUrl
...
<input name="codigo" type="text"class="form-control" value="@Model.id"/>
...
```

---

> Te dejo un workshop que hizo el buen amigo [@Fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx) sobre ASP.net MVC desde cero, espero te sea de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY + código fuente en Github https://github.com/fredyfx/UPAOnetStackOverflowES-ASPnetMVC

Comment: es necesario configurar el routes? pregunto pues por lo que ya viene configurado cuando usas MVC5

Comment: @ByGroxD Aveces si y aveces no, porque si solo vas a usar rutas que siempre estarás pasando un parámetro `id` pues con la ruta por default, en cambio si recibes un parámetro `idEmpresario`, es necesario configurar una ruta en vez de `id` pones `idEmpresario` en la ruta nueva

Comment: Amigo acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, por favor podrias revisarla, mi idea es la siguiente, tengo una tabla y en ella una persona quiero que al darle un clic me  lleve a esa url para crear un familiar para esa persona y ese id o codigo que esta en la url se pase a un input, gracias

Comment: @ByGroxD necesitarías definir una ruta nueva, y tu controlador de la vista recibir un parámetro como lo explico en el apartado _sin usar un modelo_